# Tagging LaTeX for conversion to XML

Tags: labels

The author I work with plans to publish an audio version of his work at some point. They want to use IBM SSML to configure the voices. In order to make the LaTeX source ready for conversion to SSML, I would like to tag the dialogs with the character tags. There will be some manual editing of the SSML after it is scripted from LaTeX, of course, but at least some tagging should be done in LaTeX. My initial idea was to use labels along these lines:

```
\label{narrator}A and B had a lively conversation:

\label{direct:A,question}``What?'' A asked and said: ``Whatever.''

\label{direct:B,exclamation}``That!'' B replied and smirked: ``Nothing.''
```

The only concern I have is that this approach would produce many identical labels. Can that be detrimental to typesetting the work in any way? Are there other approaches that could facilitate future conversion of the source to SSML?

The specifics of conversion to SSML are out of scope for this question; only the preparation of LaTeX to it is. The document type is `memoir` and it is going to be 1-2 MB in size so I do expect thousands of identical labels.

Comment: I would use custom commands, like `\question{direct:A}`, `\exclamation{direct:B}`. The conversion to XML can be done using `tex4ht`. I've done some experiments with [Aeneas](https://www.readbeyond.it/aeneas/) in the past and I was able to produce EPUB file with synchronized text and audio.